# Prevent the keyboard from pushing up the bottom navigation bar

Tags: javascript, css

These images resume perfectly the problem I have and the found solution.

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pU4r.png) [Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpqKr.png)

I thought that using the focus and blur events might be a solution, but it turns out that when I click on the OS back button, as I mentioned in the image, the input stays in the focus state, so what could be the solution?

*Edited*

```js
const textfield = document.getElementById("textfield"),
  bottomNav = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom-nav")[0],
  viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

textfield.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  bottomNav.style.top = `${viewportHeight - 56}px`;
  bottomNav.style.bottom = "auto";
});
textfield.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  bottomNav.style.top = "auto";
  bottomNav.style.bottom = 0;
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
}

.header,
.bottom-nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: red;
}
.header {
    top: 0;
}

.bottom-nav {
    bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 72px 16px;
}

.textfield {
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
    <main class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="textfield" class="textfield" />
    </main>
<nav class="bottom-nav"></nav>
```

If you add something to make the body scrollable, in Chrome for Android it works like a charm, but in Firefox it breaks, I don't know how it behaves in Safari as I don't have an iPhone, but basically the behavior it has in Chrome is the ideal state.

Comment: Show html and styles

Comment: I will edit the question then.

Comment: I think its the `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` causing your problem? When they keyboard opens the viewport changes size. Try calculating a `top` value instead of `bottom: 0`

Comment: try reducing  .bottom-nav z-index to 0 or 1 or -1

Comment: Check out the latest edition.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not bulletproof, but it works the same in both Firefox (105) and Chrome (106) for Android.

Add this to the CSS and change the JavaScript.:

```css
.bottom-nav--hide {
    top: 100vh;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

```js
const bottomNav = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom-nav")[0],
    viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    let vh = window.innerHeight;
    if (vh < viewportHeight) {
        bottomNav.classList.add("bottom-nav--hide");
    } else {
        bottomNav.classList.remove("bottom-nav--hide");
    }
});
```

### Situations in which it doesn't work.

- If the user opens the site in portrait and goes to landscape.
- If the user rescales the window and the height is less than the original height.